# Android facebook api get friend's life events

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can see friends life event's in facebook app, but i can't retrieve it from my app through `/me/feed` or `/me/home` or by FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

Is there any way(FQL or Graph API) to get friend's life events in my app?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible via the Graph API and/or FQL.

Answer (score 0):

Friend permissions are deprecated, you cannot get any details of your friends anymore. See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

FQL is deprecated too, btw. But it will still work in older Apps until 2016.

Also, life events are not available via the Graph API at all.

Comment: And furthermore, life events are not available via the Graph API... :-)

Comment: yeah, i will add this for clarification :)