# android facebook friends details and get other details

Tags: android, facebook

I want to create an application with use of Facebook.

some highlights of app is like

Connect facebook and google accounts. Gather info for user profiles: name, bio, profile picture.

1]fb-events that the user has created (or attended) and add them to my applications's calendar in the app

2]The app should create your fb-events in the app with the following information:
- Cover photo
- Title
- About text
- Location
- Time (Tuesday, March 17 at 19:00 - 21:00)

But read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360875/android-facebook-api-get-friends-life-events)

is it possible please guid me

Thanks
Pragna Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways 
1. using offical documention of fb
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
2. using social auth 
    https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/
both are easy but if you do by social auth your other social sites like twitter,linkdn and instragram and many more will also cover with facebook.

Comment: can i get all details like name,locations,events and all of my facebook friends?

Comment: can you please provide some examples also?

Comment: social auth is inbulit lib ..link i have posted ..u can go there and follow the steps ...for facebook integration we use mostly inbuilt code that is available on offical site